# can i use xpath to set values to elements?

Tags: xpath

can i use xpath to set element properties ?

```
/html/body/form[@id='search']/select[@name='category' and @value='apple' and @type='select-one']
```

Answer (score 4):

> XPath, the XML Path Language, is a
>   query language for selecting nodes
>   from an XML document.

To set the value you can use something like a DOM parser and setAttribute('value', 'foo');

It might help if you actually told us if that returned anything or not. You can use count() to see if it returns anything, if not noticeable.

Answer (score 3):

you use XPATH to traverse an XML document, but to transform XML you typically use XSL or a DOM parser within JavaScript, C# or some other high level language.

Answer (score 2):

No, but once you find the element you're looking for, you can set its properties by other means.

Answer (score 1):

No, XPath is just to query XML documents

Comment: is the above xpath valid at least  for querying the element ?

Comment: sure, if you have an XML document like <html><body><form><select name='category' value='apple' type='select-one'>...</select></form></body><html>

Comment: important to note: you really needs to have a xml file like that; you can't use XPath to look into your HTML element proprieties, ok?